# when chrony sync time wtih local，why the Last Sample is not zero

Tags: linux, ntpd

**Linux version: Centos 7**

**chrony version: 3.2**

**chrony.conf:**

```
driftfile /var/lib/chrony/drift
local stratum 10
server localhost
rtcsync
makestep 1.0 3
logdir /var/log/chrony
allow
```

---

### This picture is about chrony:

[image: chronyc sources -v]

---

### This picture is about ntpd, why they are different:

[image: ntpq -p]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The offset printed by `chronyc sources` is not zero, because it's an actual NTP measurement. `chronyd` sent an NTP request to itself and responded. As the delays of the messages were not perfectly symmetric, there is a non-zero offset. Trying to synchronize a client to itself is not a good idea as it may create a positive feedback loop and throw the clock off. The `local stratum` directive alone is enough to serve the local time when not synchronized to a time source.

The LOCAL source printed by ntpq is different. It is specified in `ntp.conf` as `127.127.1.0`. Addresses in the 127.127.0.0/16 network are special addresses for `ntpd`. They specify reference clocks and the LOCAL reference clock driver always returns zero offset. While it looks like a valid IPv4 address of localhost, there are no NTP packets actually exchanged.